# I can't deploy my frontend react on a private server with pm2, node_modules and vite

Tags: reactjs, node.js, deployment, frontend, pm2

I have two ports defined for http: 1632 and 1633. On 1632 is running the backend without any problem.
pm2 shows me this error in the log.

my server es ubuntu 22.04

```
0|npm      | error when starting preview server:
0|npm      | Error: Build failed with 1 error:
0|npm      | vite.config.js:6:7: ERROR: Unexpected "�"
```

but this is my vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  preview: {port:443, host:true}
});
```

this is my .env

```
VITE_BASE_URL=http://localhost:1632/api
```

my package.json is this:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview --port=443"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.0",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.18.5",
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.49.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.17.0"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```

I tried to reinstall node_modules and pm2 dependencies too, but nothing works.